# MYSQL: Standard deviation on a datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, statistics, unix-timestamp

I need to calulate the Standard deviation on a datetime. The field is the BirthDate of the participants. I know you can use the STD function so i tried:

```
SELECT STD(  `BirthDate` ) 
FROM  `students`
```

Now my result is the following:

```
13490285387.12395
```

What i dont know what is. Its probarly calculated from the UNIX timestamp, so i assummed seconds or ms.

```
23085731336 seconds to years = 731
23085731336/1000 seconds to years = 0.731
```

0.731 years seems like a reasonable answer, Can someone tell me if my assumption is correct or i am doing something wrong.

Comment: That is a difficult question but I suspect not, I tried this - STD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE)) (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) - (UNIX_TIMESTAMP is seconds since 1970), and got a very different result. This should give an answer in seconds however so hopefully that helps.

Comment: By using your method i indeed get a very different result. I think this one is far closer to my estimate. But i am still not 100% sure. would love if someone could verify this.